# How to tune the hyperparameters for oneclass SVM while doing unsupervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, unsupervised-learning

For my task, I am doing unsupervised learning and I am trying to find the best possible value of the parameters `gamma` and `nu` in [OneClassSVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html#sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.score_samples).

I did the following:

```
nus = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
gammas = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
tuned_parameters = {'kernel' : ['rbf'], 'gamma' : gammas, 'nu': nus}
tuned_ocsvm = OneClassSVM()
clf = GridSearchCV(tuned_ocsvm, tuned_parameters, cv=10)
clf.predict(maximum.values[:,[1]])
```

and I am getting, the following error:

```
NotFittedError: This GridSearchCV instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

The above error makes sense since the instance wasn't fitted which led me to to do this:

```
nus = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
gammas = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
scores = ['recall']
tuned_parameters = {'kernel' : ['rbf'], 'gamma' : gammas, 'nu': nus}
tuned_ocsvm = OneClassSVM()
clf = GridSearchCV(tuned_ocsvm, tuned_parameters, cv=10, scoring = scores, refit = False)
clf.fit(maximum.values[:,[1]])
```

and this gave the following error:

```
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'
```

But I don't have the 'true' values available since I am doing unsupervised learning.

Is there any other way the best parameters can be found for the same?

Comment: What unsupervised problem are you trying to tackle? Clustering? Outlier prediction? Density estimation?

Comment: @Rickyfox: Both clustering and outliers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsupervised *learning*, as commonly done in anomaly detection, does not mean that your *evaluation* has to be unsupervised.
In order to evaluate different models and hyper-parameters choices you should have validation set (with labels), and to estimate the performance of your final model you should have a test set (with labels).

Usually the assumption is that all data in the training set is "normal" (not an anomaly). So you need to find (or create) some anomalies in your dataset. This can be done through Exploratory Data Analysis.

Should have least 20 anomaly instances, but something like 200-2000 is of course better. Then you remove those from the candidates for training data, and split out a validation and testset. A split train/validation/test ratio might be 80/10/10 or 60/20/20 for the the negative class (normal), and then 0/50/50 for the labeled anomalies (so if you have 20 labeled anomalies, 10 for validation and 10 for test).

Once you have this you can perform gridsearch. Though unfortunately scikit-learn GridSearch does not let you specify train and validation sets manually, but you an use ParameterGrid and implement it manually. I would definitely plot the scores across hyperparameters and chose manually, as with a small validation set the scores can be pretty noisy.

Comment: Calling it unsupervised anomaly detection, but tunning hyperparameters with "anomaly" entries is useless for real use cases but typically done ... and in my opinion, it is not correct to call it unsupervised. Using labeled data for evaluation is necessary, but not for tuning. Then go to one-shot or few-shot learning ...

Comment: Do you have a good process/reference for how to do evaluation and tuning of hyperparameters, without the used of labeled validation data? I agree the naming is not the clearest

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I get annoyed at all the people who call their work unsupervised anomaly detection, but use labelled examples to achieve their results. The unsupervised aspect is only about representation learning but in my opinion very misleading for people new in this field. And as I observed: few/one-shot learning mostly results in better accuracy ...

Comment: Few/one-shot learning are usually not one-class modelling though? Methods that are not one-class are less likely to do well on new kinds of anomalies, because they rely on the data distribution of the anomaly samples (which changes), not just the data distribution of the normal samples (which is relatively stable)

Answer (score 0):

About the outlier removal using OneClassSVM: since there is no ground truth, there isn't a clear rule to choose `nu` and `gamma` values.

You can try to use KDE (anomaly detection) to find abnormal `gamma` or `nu` based on what you have in your dataset history. Then you can avoid them later.